# Talk to Host machine's Dbus through Docker

Tags: docker, dbus

I have my application that performs certain task with the help of [NFS-Ganesha](https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/wiki).
During this it talks to NFS-Ganesha through DBus.

But now I am planning to run NFS-Ganesha on Docker Container.
(My application will still run normally on Host machine & not on docker container.)

But the problem is, I have to make some arrangments so that **My application on Host machine** & **NFS-Ganesha on Docker Container** can talk each other through **DBus**.

I don't have any idea, what configuration changes will be required.

I would be very grateful if you have any answer/suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

If running your container in *privileged mode* is an option for you (note that this is generally discouraged, see below), you can mount the host’s D-Bus socket into the container:

```
docker run --privileged \
  -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket \
  --name your-container
```

These paths will work both the host and container are Ubuntu. They might differ on other systems.

#### Note on Security

As I said above, it is generally discouraged to run containers in privileged mode because it bypasses all isolation features:

> Docker’s --privileged flag effectively disables all isolation features. The containers may have different PID and MNT namespaces as well as cgroups profiles applied. But with the --privileged flag running on a Docker container, a user — and inadvertently, an attacker — has access to the hard drives attached to the host.

(Source: https://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/why-running-a-privileged-container-in-docker-is-a-bad-idea/)

Comment: Just a note here- `--privileged` already gives access to everything dbus needs.